# mu4e gmail smtp settings

Tags: mu4e, email, smtpmail

I'm trying to use `mu4e` to send/receive email with my Gmail account. I've followed what I believe is the official documentation [here](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/), but I think some of the description here seems outdated. As far as receiving mail goes, everything's fine - I'm using `offlineimap` and an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) from Google (which is saved in an encrypted file).

Sending mail is a problem  - I write my message and hit `^C ^C`, and am then prompted for an smtp username and password.

Here is the template that I'm using in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'smtpmail)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
   starttls-use-gnutls t
   smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
   smtpmail-auth-credentials
     '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 "USERNAME@gmail.com" nil))
   smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

which is from the [standard Gmail template](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Gmail-configuration.html#Gmail-configuration) with USERNAME appropriately changed.

I want to keep this setup relatively simple and I've seen [other issues](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56426/mu4e-problem-sending-email-with-gmail) with more complicated arrangements that I want to avoid to begin with.

It does seem to me that I need a password of some kind -- how do I set this up (and why isn't this mentioned in this standard template?!). I played around with `gnus` before, is the simplest solution getting another app password and saving it to some `auth.gpg` file?

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I created another app password from my google account and stored it in `.authinfo.gpg`, which is [formatted as per the Gnus Gmail instructions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail#h5o-1)

```
machine smtp.gmail.com login <USER> password <APP-PASSWORD> port 587
```

To get this to work, I added

```
   smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
```

into the `smtpmail` config block shown in my initial question.

There may be something more convenient (I now have to separate app passwords for `offlineimap` and for `smtpmail`) but I'll figure that out as I go along.

Comment: This seems correct. I also have separate passwords for `mbsync` and `smtpmail`.

Comment: Just wondering why separate gmail app passwords? I'm using the same for `offlineimap` as well as `smtp`

Comment: @Kayo sorry, I switched to `isync`/`mbsync` shortly after and forgot why this was a problem

Comment: @nonreligious thanks for your reply

Comment: Does anyone knows knows how to create an app-password without having to provide your phone number to google?